# Creating duplicate linked Google spreadsheets that share copy and formatting

Tags: google-sheets

I'm looking to create a content calendar on one Google Drive and then have that exact content calendar (copy, formatting, and any new rows that get added) shared as a tab in a spreadsheet on another Google Drive. All of the cell inputs will be text based, I'm not sure if that makes any difference. Is this even remotely possible?

**Additional information** (from the comments):

Ideally I'd want it to happen in real time. Basically what I want to achieve is I would like one team to be able to write a bunch of coop and have their own approvals process (with a specific set of users who can see the document). I then want this document to get automatically updated in the tab of a master document so a different team can see what is being done. They might need to edit some copy if the approvals are bad but mostly its for oversight. I then want to replicate this out across about 30 teams.

So the structure would be: Team 1 [has read/write privileges and their own set of users for a document] Same for Team 2-30 Then there is a master document that pulls in all of the sheets from Teams 1-30 all in one place. This is a different set of users.

Comment: Why do you need to create a duplicate instead of sharing the original spreadsheet?

Comment: It's possible to run a script that syncs the sheet with master spreadsheet at some intervals. Would this be acceptable?

Comment: Do say more about what you want to achieve. Would a shared Google Calendar do the job? People could subscribe to that, rapidly see its changes on their calendars, and add personal notes to the events.

Comment: Ideally I'd want it to happen in real time.

Basically what I want to achieve is I would like one team to be able to write a bunch of coop and have their own approvals process (with a specific set of users who can see the document). I then want this document to get automatically updated in the tab of a master document so a different team can see what is being done. They might need to edit some copy if the approvals are bad but mostly its for oversight.

I then want to replicate this out across about 30 teams.

Comment: So the structure would be:
Team 1 [has read/write privileges and their own set of users for a document]
Same for Team 2-30

Then there is a master document that pulls in all of the sheets from Teams 1-30 all in one place. This is a different set of users.

Comment: The additional details should be included in the question. Also it's important to mention the username that you are replying to so the related user will get a notification. It's not necessary to mention the author of the question or answer as they will be notified of comments to their posts. See "Replying in comments" section of http://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Comment: It's still not clear to me the scenario. What do you mean by "on one Google Drive", "their own approval process",  "Team 2-30", "Team 1-30"?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using an array of `importrange()` functions. This cannot import the formatting information, which is not possible without Apps Script, but it will pull in multiple sheets and aggregate them into one list, which you can then sort with an additional formula. Keep in mind that each imported sheet will have to have the same number of columns. For example, if you have four sheets to import with 4 columns each, the import formula will be as follows:

```
={
importrange("url_to_sheet_1", "Approved!$A:$D");
importrange("url_to_sheet_2", "Approved!$A:$D");
importrange("url_to_sheet_3", "Approved!$A:$D");
importrange("url_to_sheet_4", "Approved!$A:$D")
}
```